# Change size of hover text in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, htmlwidgets

I am building a Plotly plot based on a ggplot in R. I would like to increase the size of the text in the hover boxes. Suppose I have a scatterplot like this:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(a = sample(1:50, 30, T), 
                b = sample(1:50, 30, T), 
                col = factor(sample(1:3, 30, T)))

gg <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b, color = col), data = d)

p <– plotly_build(gg)
p
```

Is there a way to change the size of the hover text?

Comment: please see my answer below for what I believe is the correct way to accomplish this in R

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there seems to be no built-in way to pass additional attributes to define the hover appearance directly via plotly (see [github issue #102](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/102)). However, in the issue description you see the name of the class used for the hover text, which is `.hovertext`. The simplest solution would be to save you plotly as an HTML file and add the CSS below by hand somewhere in the `<head>` part of the HTML. In case you want to change the size of the legend text as well, keep the `.legendtext` lines, if not erase them.

```
<style type="text/css">
.hovertext text {
    font-size: 100px !important;
}
.legendtext {
    font-size: 30px !important;
}
</style>
```

If you want to inject the CSS using R instead of doing it by hand you have several options.

```
# the CSS we want to inject
css <- '
<style type="text/css">
.hovertext text {
    font-size: 100px !important;
}
.legendtext {
    font-size: 30px !important;
}
</style>'

library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
```

## 1: modify the HTML file after creation

```
x <- as.widget(p)                                 # convert to htmlwidget object 
saveWidget(x, file="test_edited_1.html")          # and save to file
l <- readLines("test_edited_1.html")              # read file
h <- paste(l, collapse= " ")               
hh <- strsplit(h, "<head>")[[1]]                  # split where head appears
h.new <- paste(hh[1], css, hh[-1], collapse=" ")  # insert CSS
writeLines(h.new, "test_edited_1.html")           # write back to file
```

## 2: modify the object from which the HTML file is created

```
x <- as.widget(p)                                 # convert to htmlwidget object 
# add a the code directly into <head> using `htmltools::htmlDependency`
x$dependencies <- list(
    htmlDependency(
        name = "custom",
        version="1",
        src="",
        head=css)  
    )
saveWidget(x, file="test_edited_2.html")
```

While the second works, I am not sure if it is a proper use of `htmlDependency`.

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 10):

There has been an [update](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/1582) to plotly recently that allows you to change various characteristics of the hover text.  Here's an example in R:

```
plot_ly(x=c(1:42),
        y=c(1:42),
        text=c(1:42),
      type="bar")%>%
  layout(
    title = paste("Top 42"),
    hoverlabel = list(font=list(size=10))
  )
```

There are also options to change font color, bgcolor, and more.