# R Plotly - Change font and opacity of hoverinfo

Tags: r, fonts, plotly, opacity

I am trying to change the font and opacity of the hoverinfo box within my plotly graph (using R). I have used the following code but cannot work out how to change the font or the opacity of the hover box, if this is even possible?

`plotC <- plot_ly(tg, x = ~FINPERCH, y = ~JourneyTime, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',color = ~PeakDirection, colors=pal, linetype = ~PeakDirection,height = 500, width = 1200,`

`hoverinfo= 'text', text = ~paste("<b>Period: </b>", FINPERCH,'<br><b>Direction / Peak :</b>', PeakDirection,'<br><b>Average Journey Time:</b>',JourneyTime,'mins'))%>%`

I do not want to add any annotations to the graph itself. I only want to set the font and opacity of the hover.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `htmltools::htmlDependency` to add CSS to the plot, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076722/change-size-of-hover-text-in-plotly):

```
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x=~cyl, y=~mpg) 


x <- as_widget(p)                                 # convert to htmlwidget object 
# add a the code directly into <head> using `htmltools::htmlDependency`
x$dependencies <- c(x$dependencies,
  list(
    htmlDependency(
      name = "custom",
      version="1",
      src="",
      head='
        <style type="text/css">
        .hovertext {
            opacity: 0.5
        }
        </style>
      '
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you @aocall !

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the right solution for you, could you accept the answer?